# Previewing data type of vector layers in QGIS Browser?

Tags: qgis, vector, qgis-browser

One of the features I really like about ArcGIS is that in the Catalog pane, it will show you what vector data type (whether it be point, line, or polygon) a layer is in the little icon, which is quite helpful especially when dealing with municipal or federal data that is poorly named and I have to guess what it will be. Being able to tell what type of shapefile it is saves me time waiting for a large file to render.

I know QGIS can tell what type of vector shapefile each layer is in the properties, is there a way to make the icon update according to the data type? A screenshot is shown below as to what I mean.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS does already do that.  Might have to check your options to see what settings are enabled.

[image]

[image]